# How do Secret Super Training Prizes get Rewarded?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I recently got a Shiny Litwick, and I decided that it would look better as a Chandelure. I needed a Dusk Stone, so I went over to Secret Super Training and fought Aeigislah around 7 times. Each time though, I would get Star Dust or a Hard Stone. I checked the Wiki, and it says that the Dusk Stone is a high tier score. I always get it in over 2:40 Min remaining, what decides that I get a Dusk Stone instead of a lower tier reward?

Comment: From memory You need to get a time within a certain 10 seconds, like 2:10-2:20. I can't remember the exact time, But even then it's not a guarantee that you'll get the Dusk Stone unfortunately

Comment: If you find an exact answer then post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to get a dusk stone.

1. You can get one from the Team Flare member in Laverre City AFTER you beat the Elite Four. He will be standing right on the path right before the Pokeball Factory.
2. Defeat the [Psychic Inver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150736/what-determines-psychic-invers-reward) guy on Route 18.
3. Find the stone in Terminus Cave
4. Beat the Aegislah super training with a time of 2:10 - 2:20 remaining - It's not a guarantee to get the stone even if you beat it within that time. But it is the requirement to be able to get it. Just like other super training games you must beat  within that time to get other stones.

Comment: Even though it does have extra info, it is very helpful for my mini-question.

Comment: Do you mean that the remaining time must be *at least* some uncertain cutoff that lies between 2:10 and 2:20, or that the time has to actually be between 2:10 and 2:20?  For example, could a time of 2:30 earn an evolutionary stone?

Comment: @jwodder You MUST have between 2:10 - 2:20 remaining to get an evolution stone. So if you beat the game with 2:12.7 remaining you could possibly get a stone, it doesn't guarantee you will get one but it's the only timeframe of which you can receive one. A time of 2:30 would never yield a stone.

Comment: I don't think it neccesarily has to be between 2:10 and 2:20. I once got a stone with a time of 2:25

Comment: The 2:10-2:20 thing is definitely false. I've gotten plenty of Dusk Stones with over 2:40 left on the timer.